# showing that $w$ is continuous at $1$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $w\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Assume $w$ is increasing. Assume $w(1) = 2$.  Assume the sequence $2 + \frac{(−1)^n}{n}$ belongs to the image of $w$. How is $w$ continuous at $1$? This doesn't really make sense to me. I've seen a few proofs but can't really follow how they proved this. Thanks!

Comment: Use theorem 4.6 in Rudin's PMA. The problem is that given only _one_ sequence for which the function converges to its value on that point, doesn't guarantee that _every_ sequence will converge (as required by theorem 4.2). To show this extra condition, use the fact that $w$ is increasing plus this sequence.

Comment: thanks, just looked up the theorem but it's not clicking for me still not seeing how w would be continuous at 1

Comment: Assume that $w$ is not continuous. That will allow you to build a new sequence $y_n$ that converges to $1$ yet $w(y_n)$ does not converge to $2$. Why does that lead to a contradiction (using the fact $w$ is increasing and the sequence $x_n$ that you are given ($w(x_n)$ converges to 2)).

Comment: I cleaned up your question. Please let me know if anything needs to be corrected (or correct it yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's fix a small $\epsilon>0$ and find a $\delta >0$ making the following implication hold:

$$|x-1| < \delta \Rightarrow  |w(x)-2| < \epsilon .$$

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be odd, and be such that $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$.

Then, there is an $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $w(x_1) = 2 - \frac{1}{N}$. (Note the $(-1)^n$ term simplifies by my specification that $N$ is odd). By the increasingness, we must have that  $x_1 < 1$. Also, by increasingness, for all $x \in (x_1, 1)$ we know that

$$  2 - \frac{1}{N} = w(x_1) \leq w(x) \leq w(1) = 2 .$$

There is also an $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $w(x_2) = 2 + \frac{1}{N+1}$.  By the increasingness, for all $x \in (1,x_2)$ we know that

$$  2 + \frac{1}{N+1} = w(x_2) \geq w(x) \geq w(1) = 2 .$$

Hence, for all $x \in (x_1,x_2)$,

$$|w(x)-2| \leq \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon. $$

Finally we note that since $x_1 < 1 < x_2$ we can pick a little $\delta >0$ such that $(1-\delta, 1+\delta) \subset (x_1,x_2)$, and the above inequality therefore holds for all $x \in (1-\delta, 1+\delta)$, that is for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|x-1| < \delta$.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I just have a question: So, you conclude that |w(x)−2 |≤ 1/N < ϵ and this holds true for all x ∈ℝ satisfying |x−1|<δ. Can I just have a little bakground info on why this specifically proves that we have continuity at 1 , all the steps make sense though! Thanks for the help

Comment: That's a pleasure. The definition of $w$ is continuous at $1$ is: for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |w(x)-w(1)| < \epsilon$. In this case, $w(1) = 2$, so this is what I show. Hope this helps!

Comment: You state that there is an x2 in R such that f(x1)=2 + 1/(N+1), should that say f(x2)=2 + 1/(N+1)? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thanks, I corrected this. There was also an inquality that was the wrong way round in the third display. Now also corrected.